# Avoid IF ELSE Branching

Tags: c, branch-prediction

I was looking at branching, and I wanted to avoid branching in a loop, which basically was doing this

```
for(z=0; z<8; z++){
   if(0xff&&(array[z])!=0 ){
       break;
   }
 }
```

so my plan was actually to replace it with the following :

```
for(z=0; z<8; z++){
     (0xff&&(array[z])==0 ) ? continue :  break;
}
```

but well, this does not work, and I understand why, but would like to know if there is another way of doing this, in a similar way.

Thanks

Comment: Your "plan" IS using branching; its just using a different syntax to say it.

Comment: Apart from the reasons this doesn't work as is, the conditional operator is a branch too, so you wouldn't have achieved your goal anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to avoid branching in the loop? (Additional note: `0xff && array[z] != 0` is equivalent to `array[z] != 0`)

Comment: Actually, just `for (z = 0; z < 8 && (0xff & array[z]) == 0; z++)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could include the break condition with the termination condition (i.e. z<8) of the for statement.  But you can't avoid branching; this is just a different way to express it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `?` is still a branch, it's just another way of writing `if`.
As you only have 8 indicies, you can unroll your loop.

`inline int getZ()
{
    if (array[0] & 0xff) return 0;
    if (array[1] & 0xff) return 1;
    ... and so on
}`

As a side note, you want to use the `&` bitwise operator, not the boolean `&&` operator, otherwise your expression will always be true.

Comment: I'd leave the loop unrolling to the compiler until I encounter evidence that (1) the compiler doesn't unroll and (2) it makes a difference.

Comment: @delnan Neither of us can know that, but at least it gives the questioner an option to try.  If he's working on a small microcontroller for example this could make a very big difference.

Comment: OP can't even get their code to compile, much less run correctly. That should take priority, don't you think? ;-) I'm not generally opposed to teaching optimization tricks, but I can think of dozens of thinks that probably benefit OP more than this (including other micro optimizations that are less likely to be pointless because the compiler already did them).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int bits = 0;
for(z=0; z<8; z++) bits |= array[z];
if ((bits & 0xff) != 0) printf("Found it!\n");
```

The above has only one extra if, rather than one-per-loop-iteration.  If your goal is to make the code's execution faster, it might help or it might not.  (My guess is it won't make a lot of difference if you're running on a modern CPU)

Answer (score 0):

```
int z = 0;
while(z<8 && (0xff&&array[z]==0)) z++;
```

NOTE: maybe you meant to mask array[z] with 0xff? (i.e. using the bit-wise & operator?)

Comment: yes I did, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Your negation of the expression is wrong.

`0xff&&(array[z])!=0` is `true` when `0xff` is `true` (which is always true) and `(array[z])!=0` is `true`.

So `0xff&&(array[z])!=0` evaluates to `(array[z])!=0` which on negation gives `(array[z]==0)`

So you need to modify `(0xff&&(array[z])==0 ) ? continue :  break;` to `(array[z]==0) ? continue : break;`

Comment: You're not wrong, but this work can be cut down by either dropping the pointless conjunction w/ TRUE or fix the erroneous use of `&&` in place of `&`.

Comment: What do you mean by _fixing the erroneous use of && in place of &_?

Comment: The condition should involve `0xff & array[z]`, not `0xff && array[z]`. The latter makes no sense, and OP [has stated that the former was intended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046899/avoid-if-else-branching/22047240?noredirect=1#comment33428001_22047089).

Comment: Right. It didn't come to my mind that `0xff&&(array[z])!=0` can be mistakenly written as `(0xff & array[z]) != 0`. Edited!